# GitHub Actions Automatically Restart on Completiton

Tags: github-actions

I have a GitHub Actions workflow that I want to automatically re-run once completed. I tried configuring the Action with `workflow_run` on itself but this is not allowed.

```
name: Suburb Automatic
on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["Suburb Automatic"]
    branches: [master]
    types:
      - completed
```

Is there a simple way to do this without some additional Workflow to monitor and dispatch things?

Comment: You can loop a workflow by using a PAT to send the event triggering it. For example: having a workflow which trigger on a push event, and that perform a git commit push operation to the repo during the workflow execution, will loop itself. In your case, just sending a dispatch event at the end of workflow run should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Using repository_dispatch it works.

```
name: Suburb Automatic
on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
  repository_dispatch:
    types: [auto-suburb]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Start new workflow
        uses: peter-evans/repository-dispatch@v2
        with:
          event-type: auto-suburb
```